# Как задать стиль объекту унаследованному от Button?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс:

```
public class GLine : Button
{
    public int x, y;
    Game game;
    public GLine(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Grid.SetRow(this, y);
        Grid.SetColumn(this, x);
        DataContextChanged += GLine_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void GLine_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        game = (Game)DataContext;
        Click += game.PlayerClick;
    }
}
```

Как задать объекту этого класса стиль, описанный в разметке UserControl'a, в который этот объект помещается?

TargetType = "Button" - не работает.

Comment: TargetType = "GLine " ?

Comment: @AntonShakalo Может быть как-то надо правильно указать, но у меня компилятор сразу выдал, что не знает кто такой GLine.

Comment: а если указать пространство имен, типа: `TargetType="local:GLine"`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP во блин! Сработало!

Comment: Не верю, добавьте в вопрос код разметки чтобы было видно определение пространства имен, покажите какое пространство имен имеет ваш класс и разметку того, как вы задаете стиль.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Спасибо! Пиши ответ посталю галку)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто укажите наименование класса, ну и не забудьте про пространство имен XAML, например:

```
<Style TargetType="local:GLine" ...
```